# Ruby backup gem - shared configurations?

Tags: ruby, configuration, backup, dry

I'm using meskyanichi's [backup gem](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup). By and large it does what I need it to, but I need to have multiple backups (e.g., hourly, daily, weekly).  The configurations are mostly the same but have a few differences, so I need to have multiple configuration files.  I'm having trouble finding a sane way to manage the common bits of configurations (i.e., not repeat the common parts).

The configuration files use a lot of block structures, and from what I can tell, each backup needs to have a separate config file (e.g. config/backup/hourly.rb, config/backup/daily.rb, etc).  A typical config file looks like this:

```
Backup::Model.new(:my_backup, 'My Backup') do

  database MySQL do |db|
    db.name               = "my_database"
    db.username           = "foo"
    db.password           = "bar"
    # etc
  end

  # similar for other config options

end
```

Then the backup is executed a la `bundle exec backup perform -t my_backup -c path/to/config.rb`.

My first swag at enabling a common config was to define methods that I could call from the blocks:

```
def my_db_config db
  db.name = "my_database"
  # etc
end

Backup::Model.new(:my_backup, 'My Backup') do
  database MySQL do |db|
    my_db_config db
  end
  #etc
end
```

But this fails with an `undefined method 'my_db_config' for #<Backup::Database::MySQL:0x10155adf0>`.

My intention was to get this to work and then split the common config functions into another file that I could `require` in each of my config files.  I also tried creating a file with the config code and `require`ing it into the model definition block:

```
# common.rb
database MySQL do |db|
  db.name = "my_database"
  #etc
end

# config.rb
Backup::Model.new(:my_backup, 'My Backup') do
  require "common.rb" # with the right path, etc
end
```

This also doesn't work, and from subsequent research I've discovered that that's just not the way that `require` works.  Something more in line with the way that C/C++'s `#include` works (i.e., blindly pasting the contents into whatever scope it is called from) might work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem seems to modify the execution scope of the config blocks. To work around this, you could wrap your functions in a class:

```
class MyConfig
  def self.prepare_db(db)
    db.name = "my_database"
    # etc
    db
  end
end

Backup::Model.new(:my_backup, 'My Backup') do
  database MySQL do |db|
    db = MyConfig.prepare_db(db)
  end
  #etc
end
```

You could get a bit more fancy and abstract your default config merge:

```
class BaseConfig
  @@default_sets = 
    :db => {
      :name => "my_database"
    },
    :s3 => {
      :access_key => "my_s3_key"
    }
  }

  def self.merge_defaults(initial_set, set_name)
    @@default_sets[set_name].each do |k, v|
      initial_set.send("#{k}=".to_sym, v)
    end
    initial_set
  end
end

Backup::Model.new(:my_backup, 'My Backup') do
  database MySQL do |db|
    db = BaseConfig.merge_defaults(db, :db)
  end

  store_with S3 do |s3|
    s3 = BaseConfig.merge_defaults(s3, :s3)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In newest versions of backup gem you can simple use main config file like this:

Genrate main config file:

```
root@youhost:~# backup generate:config
```

Modify file /root/Backup/config.rb like this:

```
Backup::Storage::S3.defaults do |s3|
  s3.access_key_id     = "youkey"
  s3.secret_access_key = "yousecret"
  s3.region            = "us-east-1"
  s3.bucket            = "youbacket"
  s3.path              = "youpath"
end

Backup::Database::PostgreSQL.defaults do |db|
      db.name               = "youname"
      db.username           = "youusername"
      db.password           = "youpassword"
      db.host               = "localhost"
      db.port               = 5432
      db.additional_options = ["-xc", "-E=utf8"]
end

Dir[File.join(File.dirname(Config.config_file), "models", "*.rb")].each do |model|
  instance_eval(File.read(model))
end
```

Create model file:

```
root@youhost:~# backup generate:model --trigger daily_backup \
--databases="postgresql" --storages="s3"
```

Then modify /root/Backup/models/daily_backup.rb like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8

Backup::Model.new(:daily_backup, 'Description for daily_backup') do
  split_into_chunks_of 250

  database PostgreSQL do |db|
    db.keep = 20
  end

  store_with S3 do |s3|
    s3.keep = 20
  end

end
```

With this you can simply create daily, monthly or yearly archives.